# Data provider "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" is not supported in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have been working on an ASP.NET webform project, which is recently upgraded to .NET Framework 4.8.

I have been switching between Visual Studio 2022 and Visual Studio 2019.

Issue occurs only in Visual Studio 2019 when I try to open the `.dbml` file.

Error says:

> Data provider "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" is not supported.

[image: Error]

This does not cause any error during build or debugging.

**Note**: file opens in Visual Studio 2022 without any error.

**Question**: What is the cause of the issue and How can resolve it?

Thanks

**Update**

Previously, `.dbml` file was opening without any issue in Visual Studio 2019 also.

I don't when and what caused it to occur the issue.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Introduction to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/introduction-microsoft-data-sqlclient-namespace?view=sql-server-ver16#51-target-platform-support), https://superuser.com/questions/1193196/how-to-open-dbml-in-designer-mode-with-vs ,  and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/dbml-files-not-opening-in-graphic-designer-in-vs-2/1659675

Comment: @flackoverstow I want to resolve the issue or atleast want to know cause of it.

Comment: Hum, for .net framework, you should be using System.Data, and thus you use System.Data.Sqlclient.  So, the older system would have been using System.Data, but now with 4.8, you can (should be able) to use Microsoft.Data. On the  other hand, you can keep using System.Data, and I not sure I would just out of the blue change over. It's possible that you have some library references that pre-date 4.6.1, and thus those libraries will not work with Microsoft.data. I would suggest you stick with System.Data for now.

Comment: Have you opened _Visual Studio Installer_ and checked that you have the necessary _Workloads_ and _Individual Components_ installed as mention in the URLs that I posted? Also have you checked the setting for _NuGet Package Manager_ (Tools => Options... => NuGet Package Manager => General => Default package management format)?

Comment: Yes I have necessary workloads. It used to open without any issue.